# Using OpenMP for fortran simple integration

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm using Fortran90 to solve a simple integration problem and calculating speed differences when run in parallel. I'm having trouble getting the correct result when paralleling the process using openMP.

```
program midpoint
use omp_lib
implicit none

integer :: beginning, rate, end, iteration
double precision :: sum, div, x, sum2
integer ::a,b, n

n = 100000000
a = 10
b = 0
div = dble(a-b)/n
x=b+div/2
sum = 0.0

call system_clock(beginning, rate)
do iteration=1,n
    sum = sum  + sqrt(x)*div ! evaluating sqrt(x) function
    x = x + div
end do
call system_clock(end)

print *, "Computation from single core: ", sum
print *, "elapsed time from single core: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)

x=b+div/2
sum = 0.0
sum2 = 0.0
call system_clock(beginning, rate)

!$omp parallel private(iteration, sum) shared(sum2, x)
!$omp do
do iteration=1,n
    sum = sum  + sqrt(x)*div ! evaluating sqrt(x) function
    x = x + div
end do
!$omp end do
sum2 = sum2 + sum
!$omp end parallel
call system_clock(end)

print *, "Computation from multiple cores: ", sum2
print *, "elapsed time from multiple cores: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)

end program
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've programmed a *race condition*.  In the line

```
sum2 = sum2 + sum
```

you've given threads the authority to read and write to a shared variable (`sum2`) with no control over the sequencing of operations.  The same problem arises with the next line `x = x + div` too.

Continue reading your OpenMP tutorial until you encounter the `reduction` clause which is designed for what you seem to be doing.  Learn too about the `firstprivate` clause which will initialise a thread-local variable with the value of the variable of the same name when the parallel region is first encountered.

I haven't checked the syntax carefully but it should be something like this:

```
!$omp parallel do private(iteration) firstprivate(x) shared(div) reduction(+:sum)
do iteration=1,n
    sum = sum  + sqrt(x)*div ! evaluating sqrt(x) function
    x = x + div
end do
!$omp end parallel do

! at this point the value of sum will have been 'reduced' across all threads
print *, "Computation from multiple cores: ", sum
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I reran using your edits. I'm getting exactly 1/2 the correct answer. Is it because I need the threads to add up all their individual sums?

Comment: *Is it because I need the threads to add up all their individual sums?*  Probably, but it's your algorithm and I didn't examine it for correctness, just tried to fix the OpenMP problem.

Comment: @Alex, you are getting 1/2 of the correct answer since all threads start with equal values of `x` which is wrong. Either initialise `x` properly inside the parallel region or replace `x = x + div` with `x = x0 + iteration * div` where `x0 = b + div/2` is a shared variable and `x` is private (note that multiplication is slower than addition though).